Is it possible to get a dual supply from 2S Li-ion battery which has a battery protection IC connected to it
In the image below, can the node connecting cell 1 and cell 2 be used as ground and PB+ as the positive rail and PB- as the negative rail? Those positive and the negative rails will then be regulated using to LDOs and then used to power 3 opamps and two photodiodes

Source: https://www.hycontek.com/en/products-en/3180

why would it not be possible to power a dual supply from a battery? ... just not by bypassing the battery protection circuit

@jsotola I was thinking about maybe the HY2120 will introduce some undesirable effects

Unless your circuit's power draw is 100% symmetric between the two rails, you will throw your batteries out of balance. Additionally, the HY2120's response will probably lead to undesirable effects. Not recommended.

Thanks, could you suggest a way for me to do this? And also what do you mean by HY2120 response will lead to undesirable effects? (What sort of effects)
